# Direct access to harddrive?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I was wondering how hard disk access works. Ex, how could I view/modify sectors? Im targeting Windows if that helps.
Thanks

Comment: STXXL might be of interest to you:
http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027) seems to have some relevant information on the subject:

> You can open a physical or logical
>   drive using the CreateFile()
>   application programming interface
>   (API) with these device names provided
>   that you have the appropriate access
>   rights to the drive (that is, you must
>   be an administrator). You must use
>   both the CreateFile() FILE_SHARE_READ
>   and FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags to gain
>   access to the drive.
>
> Once the logical or physical drive has
>   been opened, you can then perform
>   direct I/O to the data on the entire
>   drive. When performing direct disk
>   I/O, you must seek, read, and write in
>   multiples of sector sizes of the
>   device and on sector boundaries. Call
>   DeviceIoControl() using
>   IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY to get
>   the bytes per sector, number of
>   sectors, sectors per track, and so
>   forth, so that you can compute the
>   size of the buffer that you will need.

The [documentation of CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) also offers some clues:

> You can use the CreateFile function to open a physical disk drive or a volume, 
>   which returns a direct access storage device (DASD) handle that can be 
>   used with the DeviceIoControl function. This enables you to access the 
>   disk or volume directly, for example such disk metadata as the partition 
>   table. However, this type of access also exposes the disk drive or 
>   volume to potential data loss, because an incorrect write to a disk 
>   using this mechanism could make its contents inaccessible to the 
>   operating system. To ensure data integrity, be sure to become 
>   familiar with DeviceIoControl and how other APIs behave 
>   differently with a direct access handle as opposed to a file system handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a logical volume (e.g. c: drive) or a physical drive using win32's CreateFile() function.  With the returned handle you can read and write sectors as needed.
This page at MSDN should get you started: [CreateFile Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx)

I take no responsibility for damaged caused :-)

Comment: I got the impression that @user wanted *direct* access to the drive.

Comment: @John: do you mean that he might want to bypass Windows altogether?
When opening a physical drive you do have direct access to the contents of it... it's not soldering your own SATA controller but it's at a lower level than people usually go :-)
I'm pretty sure the Windows Driver Development Kit has samples for disk drivers if that helps.